# Posting arrays Laravel 8 - values returning as NULL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to post an array from my form to database
The form fields are showing up as NULL

HTML form excerpt:

```
@foreach (range(0,9) as $x)
<div class="row m-3 credit-card-details">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="financeCompany-{{ $x }}">Finance Company name #{{ $x }}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="financeCompany-{{ $x }}" name="creditCards[{{ $x }}][financeCompany]" value="" placeholder="Finance Company Name" />
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="creditLimit-{{ $x }}">Credit limit</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditLimit-{{ $x }}" name="creditCards[{{ $x }}][creditLimit]" value="" placeholder="$" />
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="consolidate-{{ $x }}">Consolidate this card?</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="creditCards[{{ $x }}][consolidate]" id="consolidate-{{ $x }}" value="" />
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

My Controller:

```
 public function store(CreateApplicationRequest $request, Applicant $applicant, CreditCard $creditCard)
    {       
        
        
        $applicant = Applicant::create([
            ...
        ]);
        
        $application = $applicant->application()->create([
            ...
            ]); 
                        
             
        $creditCards = $request->input('creditCards');
        foreach ($creditCards as $creditCard)
        {
            $application->creditCards()->create([
                    'financeCompany' => $request->input('financeCompany'),
                    'creditLimit' => $request->input('creditLimit'),
                    'consolidate' => $request->input('consolidate')
                ]);
        }
        
      ...
}
```

My dd results are showing up like this:

[image]

The right amount of records are being created in my  `credit_cards` table and the `application_id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are being correctly recorded, however the `financeCompany`, `creditLimit` and `consolidate` fields (from the form) are all showing up as `NULL`.

Database:

[image]

CreditCard model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'application_id',
        'financeCompany',
        'creditLimit',
        'consolidate'
    ];
```

Only the application_id is being collected by the database.

Still quite new at this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, what does the `$fillable` look like in the Model?

Comment: @jeremykenedy I have updated with excerpt from CreditCard Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your `request()` has `$creditCards` by the look of it. The values you are interested in seems to be within `$creditCards`

you need to do something like this

```
collect($creditCards)
    ->each(fn ($creditCard) => $application->creditCards()
        ->create([
            'financeCompany' => creditCard['financeCompany'],
            'creditLimit' => creditCard['creditLimit'],
            'consolidate' => creditCard['consolidate']
        ])
    );
```

or if you want to use foreach

```
foreach ($creditCards as $creditCard) {
    $application->creditCards()->create([
        'financeCompany' => creditCard('financeCompany'),
        'creditLimit' => creditCard('creditLimit'),
        'consolidate' => creditCard('consolidate')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Both of these are generating errors for me. 

The first option:
ErrorException
```Use of undefined constant creditCards - assumed 'creditCards' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) ```
The second option:
```Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\creditCard() ```
 I seem to think that the problem is coming from my definition of $creditCards:
```$creditCards = $request->input('creditCards');```

Comment: it seems i forge to add `$` in front of creditcard variable

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel I tried everything else except that!  I am so appreciative of your help :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have them declared in the `$fillable` in your model otherwise the ORM will not pick them up.

Example:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'financeCompany',
        'creditLimit',
        'consolidate',
    ];
```